# FILE_ATTRIBUTE_OFFLINE doesn't work in Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows, filesystems, offline, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I used the FILE_ATTRIBUTE_OFFLINE attribute to mark files in my filesystem to indicate that they are located on a non-real-time storage. This worked well in Windows Server 2012, but in Windows Server 2012 R2 this flag seems to be broken i.e., files aren't marked offline.

Has anyone here faced this issue? Any workarounds for this?

Cheers! 
Bharath

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general OS/server tech support.

Comment: I didn't expect any sort of tech support but a mere exchange of information. This is very much related to programming, I use this flag in the CreateFlag API.

Comment: I don't think you can just mark files as offline arbitrarily.  The file system filter responsible for the offline storage is supposed to do it.

Comment: Yeah, my module is like a file system filter.